# Character Usage Python

Tags: python, syntax

Python 3.5.2

I am trying to find out how to use characters in python (!,@,$ etc), however i haven't been able to find anything to give any help or any detail about this.

Here is an example:

```
>>> $
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

What i'm  looking for is why this is happen and an example of syntax. Or wether this simply does nothing and isn't a feature and python however if it wasn't I would assume you could use the character as a variable however you cannot.

```
>>> $ = 'Example'
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Comment: Are you looking for how Python analyzes valid syntax? https://docs.python.org/3/reference/lexical_analysis.html#identifiers

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Naming convention rules in python only allow numbers, letters, and underscores. Here specifically are the rules

> ```
> Variables names must start with a letter or an underscore, such as:
>     _underscore
>     underscore_
> The remainder of your variable name may consist of letters, numbers and underscores.
>     password1
>     n00b
>     un_der_scores
> Names are case sensitive.
>     case_sensitive, CASE_SENSITIVE, and Case_Sensitive are each a different variable.
> ```

[Here](http://www.thehelloworldprogram.com/python/python-variable-assignment-statements-rules-conventions-naming/) you can learn more about python variable assignment and naming conventions

Answer (score 2):

Generally, Python identifiers can only use [letters (from various languages), numbers, or underscores](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/lexical_analysis.html#identifiers).  Unlike JavaScript, `$` isn't a valid identifier character.  Likewise, most punctuation, including `!` and `@`, is not allowed in identifiers.

> valid characters for identifiers [in Python] are the uppercase and lowercase letters `A` through `Z`, the underscore `_` and, except for the first character, the digits `0` through `9`.

Therefore, a valid assignment might look like

```
spam = 'Example'
```

for the identifier `spam`.